# Apache in xampp failing

Tags: apache, xampp

So I'm trying to install XAMPP on my new windows 7 box. It's failing with the below error message. I've enabled debug for reference.

I've checked netstat, there are no port conflicts. Futher, I've made sure that VS 2008 redist is installed (x64, which is correct for my system). I'm not sure where to go from here.

Attempting to start Apache app...
Executing "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe"
Return code: 0
Status change detected: running
Status change detected: stopped
Apache] Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
Apache] This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Check the "/xampp/apache/logs/error.log" file
and the Windows Event Viewer for more clues

Comment: This guy has the same issue.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623181/i-cannot-run-apache

Answer (score 1):

In my own case it was because after installing, windows opened automatically a 'cmd' console, closing that console made apache work fine.