# I cannot run apache

Tags: apache, xampp

I installed xamp 1.8.1 and when I went to start Apache in the control panel, I pressed start and 2 seconds later it stops running. The control panel says this:

09:42:54 م  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
09:42:54 م  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
09:42:54 م  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
09:42:54 م  [Apache]    Check the "/xampp/apache/logs/error.log" file
09:42:54 م  [Apache]    and the Windows Event Viewer for more clues

can anyone please tell me how I can fix this problem? I tried searching for the "/xampp/apache/logs/error.log" file, but I could not find it. Thank you, for any help.

Comment: Do you have any logs in `/var/log/apache`?

Comment: Oh, waitasec. "Windows Event Viewer". Well, eff. Good luck dude, I recommend running linux in a VM if you only have windows available.

Comment: Could be a build issue, as this question was submitted just a couple minutes before yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623163/apache-in-xampp-failing

Answer (score 3):

I found that this issue was being caused by a vmware hostd.exe listening on 443

ended that process in task manager and it started fine

check in taskmanager performance > resrouce monitor >listening ports for either 80 or 443

its likely either skype or some other network ssl service such as vmware listener or similar.

possibly need to look at what that vmware hostd.exe was for now!! but at least can get some work done.

Answer (score 0):

Apache use port 80. Before running it confirm that port 80 is not used by any other program. If you are running apache on windows with sql server installed. Go to services and stop the sql service and try starting apache.